# How do I copy files, overwriting existing files?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

### Overview

How do I copy all files from one directory to another directory and overwrite all existing same-named files in the target directory with C#?

I have the following code to copy the files from one directory to another directory...

```
const string sourceDir = @"C:\AppProject\Smart\SmartStaff\site\document";
const string targetDir = @"C:\AppProject\Smart\ExternalSmartStaff\site\document";
foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir))
    File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(targetDir, Path.GetFileName(file)));
```

..., but when the target directory already contains a file with the same name as a file in the source directory, it fails with the error `System.IO.IOException: The file 'C:\AppProject\Smart\ExternalSmartStaff\site\document\SomeDocument.txt' already exists.`.

### Details

To be clear, given the following directories and files in them...

```
C:\>dir C:\AppProject\Smart\SmartStaff\site\document
 ...

 Directory of C:\AppProject\Smart\SmartStaff\site\document

09/03/2014  06:38 PM    <DIR>          .
09/03/2014  06:38 PM    <DIR>          ..
05/25/2014  08:29 PM                44 SomeDocument.txt
05/25/2014  08:32 PM                21 SomeDocument2.txt
05/25/2014  08:36 PM                21 SomeDocument3.txt
05/25/2014  08:43 PM                44 SomeDocument4.txt
               4 File(s)            130 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  128,326,766,592 bytes free

C:\>dir C:\AppProject\Smart\ExternalSmartStaff\site\document
 ...

 Directory of C:\AppProject\Smart\ExternalSmartStaff\site\document

09/03/2014  06:39 PM    <DIR>          .
09/03/2014  06:39 PM    <DIR>          ..
09/03/2014  06:39 PM                26 SomeDocument.txt
09/03/2014  06:39 PM                54 SomeDocument2.txt
               2 File(s)             80 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  128,326,766,592 bytes free
```

..., I would like `C:\AppProject\Smart\ExternalSmartStaff\site\document` to look like this after the file copy in C#:

```
C:\>dir C:\AppProject\Smart\ExternalSmartStaff\site\document
 ...

 Directory of C:\AppProject\Smart\ExternalSmartStaff\site\document

09/03/2014  06:47 PM    <DIR>          .
09/03/2014  06:47 PM    <DIR>          ..
05/25/2014  08:29 PM                44 SomeDocument.txt
05/25/2014  08:32 PM                21 SomeDocument2.txt
05/25/2014  08:36 PM                21 SomeDocument3.txt
05/25/2014  08:43 PM                44 SomeDocument4.txt
               4 File(s)            130 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  128,327,835,648 bytes free
```

How can I avoid the `IOException` and accomplish this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try this:

```
const string sourceDir = @"C:\AppProject\Smart\SmartStaff\site\document";
const string targetDir = @"C:\AppProject\Smart\ExternalSmartStaff\site\document";
foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir))
    File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(targetDir, Path.GetFileName(file)), true);
```

Basically, you just need to call a different overload of `File.Copy`.  [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx) explains that the third, `bool` parameter is to indicate whether to overwrite existing files with the files being copied.

Answer (score 8):

Rather use

[File.Copy Method (String, String, Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx)

> Copies an existing file to a new file. Overwriting a file of the same
>   name is allowed.

Where

> **overwriteType: System.Boolean**
>
> true if the destination file can be overwritten; otherwise, false.

Answer (score 5):

This is a solution

```
foreach (string path in Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    File.Copy(path, path.Replace(SourcePath, DestinationPath));
```

Answer (score 2):

The `File.Copy` method has an overload that allows for overwriting existing files with the same name.
 See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx.